# como enviar por intent un ArrayList<>?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-intent

Hola tengo el siguiente código en el activity 1 (Act1)

```
 List<String> args = new ArrayList<>();

 args.add("1");
 args.add("2");
 args.add("3");
 args.add("4");
 args.add("5");
```

y necesito enviar dicha información de "args"  al activity2  (Act2)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Act1.this, Act2.class);
intent.putExtra("args", args); ??????????????????????
startActivityForResult(intent, SECONDARY_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

como lo envió ? y como lo recibo ?

Comment: Sería interesante que nos digas si esos datos van destinados a alguna clase de tu modelo. De ser así lo mejor sería implementar `Parceable`, recuperarías los datos mediante `getParcelableExtra` y tendrías los datos mapeados en una instancia del objeto. [Aquí hay un ejemplo basado en una clase `Book`](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-pass-data-between-activities-with-android-parcelable--cms-29559).

Comment: revisando el código es tal cual .. no existe ningún modelo ni nada.  como usuaria el Parceable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solución es.

enviar de este modo

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("args", (ArrayList<String>) args);
```

o

```
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("args",  args);
```

y recibirlo de este otro

```
ArrayList<String> args = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("args");
```

el args se tratara de la misma manera de como si fuese un List.